# Exception accessing Spring managed bean from Groovy closure

Tags: spring, groovy, spring-boot

I have a simple Spring Boot application with 2 bean classes, a main class and a configuration class. Whenever I try to access the Spring managed Bank bean from a Groovy closure, I get an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGroovyObjectGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:304)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.runCommandLineRunners(SpringApplication.java:675)
    at com.example.closures.ClosuresApplication$_run_closure1.doCall(ClosuresApplication.groovy:22)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:690)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication$run.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:110)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:130)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:292)
    at com.example.closures.ClosuresApplication.main(ClosuresApplication.groovy:27)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: bank for class: com.example.closures.ClosuresApplication$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$44735576
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:423)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:439)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2027)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2012)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoGetPropertySite.getProperty(PogoGetPropertySite.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2053)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$162.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGroovyObjectGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:304)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:53)
    at com.example.closures.ClosuresApplication$_run_closure1.doCall(ClosuresApplication.groovy:22)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:110)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:122)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.example.closures.ClosuresApplication.run(ClosuresApplication.groovy:21)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.runCommandLineRunners(SpringApplication.java:672)
    ... 9 common frames omitted
```

Bank.groovy

```
@Component
final class Bank {
    final String name = 'MyBank'
    final AutomatedTellerMachine insideAtm
    final AutomatedTellerMachine outsideAtm

    @Autowired
    Bank(@Qualifier('insideAtm') final AutomatedTellerMachine insideAtm, @Qualifier('outsideAtm') final AutomatedTellerMachine outsideAtm) {
        this.insideAtm = insideAtm
        this.outsideAtm = outsideAtm
    }

    String getName() {
        return name
    }

    AutomatedTellerMachine getInsideAtm() {
        return insideAtm
    }

    AutomatedTellerMachine getOutsideAtm() {
        return outsideAtm
    }
}
```

AutomatedTellerMachine.groovy

```
final class AutomatedTellerMachine {
    final String name

    AutomatedTellerMachine(final String name) {
        this.name = name
    }

    String getName() {
        return name
    }
}
```

AppConfig.groovy

```
@Configuration
class AppConfig {

    @Bean(name = 'insideAtm')
    AutomatedTellerMachine getInsideAtm() {
        new AutomatedTellerMachine('insideAtm')
    }

    @Bean(name = 'outsideAtm')
    AutomatedTellerMachine getOutsideAtm() {
        new AutomatedTellerMachine('outsideAtm')
    }
}
```

ClosuresApplication.groovy

```
@SpringBootApplication
class ClosuresApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private Bank bank

    @Override
    void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        for (def i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            printf 'Bank %02d: %s%n', (i + 1), bank
        }

        (1..10).each {
            printf 'Bank %02d: %s%n', it, bank
        }
    }

    static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run ClosuresApplication, args
    }
}
```

The regular `for` loop works just fine, but the `.each {}` closure from Groovy gives an exception. Any ideas?

Comment: What version of Groovy?

Comment: Is this just an issue with the bank member of ClosuresApplication being private, so no setter/getter is created, and autowiring can't set the value?

Comment: Weird. I suggest filing as a bug against Groovy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have run into this problem at odd times and found that a simple work-around can fix it - add a reference to your `bank` variable in the `run` method:

```
def _bank = bank
(1..10).each {
    printf 'Bank %02d: %s%n', it, _bank
}
```

It seems to be an odd scoping issue that I have never been able to determine the real cause of.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution is converting `bank` field to groovy property by removing 'private' modifier.

```
 @Autowired
 Bank bank
```

This is slightly less visually hideous (especially if you having this issue with more than one field), but it does change access level of that field.

I've encountered a number of these issues, all seemingly related to using private fields inside various closures in spring-managed beans, specifically when the beans are 'enhanced' (proxied) by spring (EnhancerBySpringCGLIB).